# xamarin forms настройка сети android emulator в режиме моста

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator

Есть задача поднять TCP сервер на Android (как минимум) для чего используется Xamarin.forms  сам код прост для теста сейчас решил использовать пример для TcpListener c msdn. Сервер на стороне телефона клиент на десктопе.
 Проблема возникла на этапе настройки соединения в эмуляторе андроида, клиент не видит сервер. 
Вопрос как надо настаивать соединение между эмулятором и реальным компьютером?

То есть для отладки я пытаюсь организовать(надеюсь организовать) соединение типа мост. 
я пытался использовать

```
redir add tcp:5000:6000
```

в telnet терминале, команда прошла. НО результата нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

да для доступа к tcp серверу запущенному в Android-emulatore оказалось надо не так много.
И так допустим наш сервер прослушивает порт 5000 (локально для эмулятора).
Запустим командную строку Adb Android (Значок в visualStudio).
Далее вбиваем команду

```
 adb devices
```

получим что-то типа:

List of devices attached

emulator-5554   device

далее необходимо выполнить сам порт форвардинг- вводим следующую команду:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:6000 tcp:5000
```

здесь 
первый порт - порт реального компьютера

второй порт - порт внутри эмулятора.

это мне помогло.